# ActionBar's text color of actions and dropdown menus changes from Android version to another

Tags: android, android-actionbar, themes, android-5.0-lollipop

What I get on my Nexus 5 (Android 5):

[image]

What I get on my Asus Memo Pad (Android 4.2.2):

[image]

My `themes.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
    <style name="HHTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/themeGrayDarker</item>
        <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/themeWhite</item>
        <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@color/themeWhite</item>
        <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/MyApp.PopupMenu</item>
    </style>

    <!-- ActionBar styles -->
    <style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTitleText</item>
        <item name="android:background">@color/actionBarBackground</item>
    </style>

    <!-- Navigation Drawer styling -->
    <style name="NavDrawerItemSelected" parent="HHTheme">
        <item name="android:activatedBackgroundIndicator">@color/themeBlue</item>
    </style>

    <!-- ActionBar title text -->
    <style name="MyActionBarTitleText" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/themeWhite</item>
    </style>

    <!-- The beef: background color for Action Bar overflow menu -->
    <style name="MyApp.PopupMenu" parent="android:Widget.Holo.Light.ListPopupWindow">
        <item name="android:popupBackground">@color/actionBarPopupBackground</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

My `colors.xml`:

```
<resources>
    <color name="themeGray">#ff8A9199</color>
    <color name="themeGrayDarker">#ff71767d</color>
    <color name="themeLightGray">#ffeaeaea</color>
    <color name="themeDarkGray">#ff3f434b</color>
    <color name="themeRed">#ffCC292B</color>
    <color name="themeBlue">#ff002E63</color>
    <color name="themeWhite">#ffffffff</color>
    <color name="buttonNormal">@color/themeGray</color>
    <color name="buttonPressed">@color/themeBlue</color>

    <color name="actionBarBackground">@color/themeGray</color>
    <color name="actionBarPopupBackground">@color/themeDarkGray</color>
    <color name="navigationMenuBackground">@color/themeRed</color>
    <color name="activityBackground">@color/themeWhite</color>

    <!-- Relay switch state colors -->
    <color name="relay_state_off">#ff00ad00</color>
    <color name="relay_state_on">#ffcc1717</color>
    <color name="relay_state_auto">#fff0ef30</color>
    <color name="relay_state_inverse_off">#ffffffff</color>
    <color name="relay_state_inverse_on">#ffffffff</color>
    <color name="relay_state_inverse_auto">#ff000000</color>
</resources>
```

There's only one `colors.xml` file in my project. What is wrong? I need a white text color on both Android versions!

Comment: Have you tried just using Light.DarkActionBar theme? It gives you the correct action bar foreground colors for both icons and text by default.

Comment: @alanv if I use <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar</item> the actionbar disappears.

Comment: @Seraphim's have you got solution for this issue in Nexus 5

Comment: @user1767260 no solution for now, the project has been suspended.